# React Navigation is not navigating to the screen when testing with React Native Testing Library and Jest

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-navigation

I have configured everything as described in the React Native Testing Library [guide](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/react-navigation).

**Test case description -**

I load the **home screen**, tap on a list item in the **home screen** which navigates to the **movie detail screen**, and the test passes up to the point of tapping the **list item**. I can even see tapped console message in the console, but the next screen is not navigating, and the screen content is not displaying in the **screen.debug()**.

Here is my jest.setup.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup';

    jest.mock('react-native-reanimated', () => {
      const Reanimated = require('react-native-reanimated/mock');
    
      // The mock for `call` immediately calls the callback which is incorrect
      // So we override it with a no-op
      Reanimated.default.call = () => {};
    
      return Reanimated;
    });
    
    // Silence the warning: Animated: `useNativeDriver` is not supported because the native animated module is missing
    jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/NativeAnimatedHelper');
```

jest.config.js -

```
 module.exports = {
  preset: 'react-native',
  setupFiles: ['./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(jest-)?@?react-native|@react-native-community|@react-navigation)',
  ],
};
```

MovieFlow.test.tsx

```
    afterEach(() => cleanup);
        
        test('Movie flow - integration test', async () => {
          //load the app with main screen
          const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
        
          const component = (
            <NavigationContainer>
              <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="Home"
                  component={HomeScreen}
                  options={{headerShown: false}}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="MovieDetail"
                  component={MovieDetailScreen}
                  options={{headerShown: false}}
                />
              </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
          );
        
          renderWithProviders(component);
        
          //verify initial loading state
          expect(screen.queryByText('Trending now')).toBeNull();
        
          //verify data loaded state by section titles
          expect(await screen.findByText('Trending now')).toBeDefined();
        
          const listItem = await screen.findByTestId(TestIds.trendingListItem + 0);
          expect(listItem).toBeDefined();
        
          fireEvent.press(listItem);

          const newScreen = await screen.findByText('test movie');
          expect(newScreen).toBeDefined();
        
          //It should display the content of the movie detail screen here, but it's not showing
          screen.debug();
        });
```

Comment: are you sure that `press` is the right event to trigger the display content? You can try `userEvent` instead and use the `.click()` to trigger the result since its generally preferred more than `fireEvent`. See details and how to set it up here https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/setup

Comment: @TaiweiTuan I don't think pressing and clicking is the issue here, as I can see the **console.log('tapped here.')** when the item is pressed using fireEvent, as described in the React Native Testing Library guide. The problem is that it's not navigating to the next screen

Comment: Have your tried the official example, by waiting for element from new page to show up before `screen.debug()` with the `const newScreen = await screen.findByText...` part? You have done similar part earlier in your code, perhaps this is the missing piece? https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/react-navigation/#example-tests-1

Comment: @TaiweiTuan Yes, I tried it, but it does not work. After this line,`const newScreen = await screen.findByText...,` it only displays the content of the Home screen.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by updating jest.config.js as follows:

From -

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'react-native',
  setupFiles: ['./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(jest-)?@?react-native|@react-native-community|@react-navigation)',
  ],
};
```

To

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'react-native',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    './node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js',
    './jest-setup.js',
  ],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|@react-native|@react-native-community|@react-navigation)',
  ],
};
```

I made these changes as described in the [GitHub example](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/blob/main/examples/react-navigation/jest.config.js) of the React Native Testing Library, and it worked.